# How to fetch output immediately in python-rq?

Tags: flask-socketio, python-rq

I want to render output from rq immediately after it gets completed.

Currently, I am using `Job.fetch()` to fetch tasks. But I have to repeatedly check after a certain interval for that.

I am using flask-socketio to render results.

Is there some way I could fetch results from task as soon as it gets finished?

Answer (score 0):

The most probable and used way seemingly is calling `Job.fetch()` itself after a certain intervals repeatedly using flask-socketio.